# Router Static IP

Tags: router, static-ip

We have a web app run by a set of servers that communicate with each other (to load balance requests, access database etc). On our internal network we have set up these servers to have static IP addresses. So the servers can always find each other and communicate with each other.

We intend to take this entire setup (all the servers and our router to which they are connected) to a client location. The client has their own internal network. We want the people connected to their internal network to be able to access our webapp.

For this to happen, I think we need to do two things:

1. Set up port forwarding on our router so that any request intended
   for port 80 goes to one of the servers in our setup (the load
   balancing server, which handles the http requests for
   the app).
2. We will need our router to have a static IP address, so we can
   give the people at the client site a specific IP address they can go
   to to access the app.

Our router is 'Cisco RV325 Gigabit Dual WAN VPN Router' ([http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00GSQJI4E/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00GSQJI4E)).

I think I can figure out how to do step 1, by following the port forwarding instructions in the router;s manual.

I am not sure about step 2. Is this something the client's IT team will have to do? Or is it a configuration we can do our ourselves on our router, as long as they provide us with an IP address we can use?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your clients environment adding your own router might not even be needed.

First off, why are you moving your setup?
If this is a web app you can always expose it to the internet and have them connect remotely.
It really depends on what your application is / does though.

If you want to integrate your setup in your clients environment, the first step is find out what their environment is like. Chances are they have a proper network setup and can easily integrate your load-balancer + both servers without adding your router.
If you do intend to add your router regardless, you will need to conform to whatever network structure they have in place. This means you're going to have to ask them what internal ranges they use, and adjust your ranges accordingly.

So, to recap: Ask their IT department how to proceed. You can't just add a router to an existing network and expect everything to work.

Comment: The nature of the app is such that it has to be within the client's network,

Comment: We want to take our router and plug that in because we want to maintain the static ips our servers have. If those ips change we will have to change a lot of configuration on those servers. We want our setup to be as close to plug and play as possible. And be as quickly operational as possible.

Comment: If it's your router, giving it a static IP is something you will have to do, and the client's IT department should give you the IP that you are to use. However I'd like to quickly note that if you want to market this application, you should really allow for the IP to be dynamically and easily configured... You're going to shoot yourself in the foot sooner or later if you keep things opaque.

Comment: Thank you for your input and suggestion. So the router's configuration page should have a place for setting static ip?

Comment: @septerr It's been a while since I worked with the RV325, but if I recall correctly the IP was configured in the Network - Wan settings menu.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for seeking so much info, but the manual for the router : http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/routers/csbr/rv320/administration/guide/en/rv32x_ag_en.pdf. Page 20 seems to have the information for setting the static WAN IP. Should I be asking the client IT team, only the IP address or should I be asking them for the other info as well - subnet mask, default gateway, dns server address? My guess is I will have to ask them for all that info. But want to make sure (I am not a network person at all as you can tell!).